# High level solution of using DDB, Kinesis, and SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sns, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

Saying that in DDB, there's a column called `publishTime`, I'm seeking a "scanner" which can periodically (e.g., every 5 mins) scan the table, and if `publishTime` is before current time, send that row to SNS. I'm thinking about developing a polling service with Kinesis stream detector for this, but am not sure if there's any solutions for periodically scan, is Kinesis Firehose useable for this use case? Thanks

Comment: I am not really sure whether DynamoDB is suitable for your usecase if you need this functionality. Scanning the whole table every 5 minutes can get extremely expensive if you have large table. Think about how you could leverage DynamoDB streams if possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay within AWS, my recommendation would be to use **Cloudwatch Events** to fire off a **lambda** function every 5 minutes - the lambda function would query the DDB and send the entries to SNS.

Kinesis doesn't seem like the right tool here.

Comment: Thanks EJ! Since I have already built a polling service listens to DDB stream, I would like to build things based on it. It sounds like I can setup Cloudwatch which triggers Kinesis stream, and then the polling service handles it, right?